# How to convert dbase III files to mysql?

Tags: mysql, csv, parsing, converters, dbf

is ist possible to convert .DBF files to any other format?
Does anybody knows a script, that can be used to convert .DBF files to an mysql query.

It would be also fine, to convert the DBF files to CSV files.
I always got problems with the codec of the DBF files.

Konstantin

Answer (score 1):

https://www.dbase.com/Knowledgebase/faq/import_export_data.asp

> Q: How do I export data from a dBASE table to a text file?
>
> A: Exporting data from dBASE to a text file is handled through the COPY TO command.
>
> Like the APPEND FROM command, there are a number of ways to use this command.  Here we are only interested in it's most basic use.  Once you understand how to use this command, you can go to your on-line help for further details on what can be accomplished with the COPY TO command.
>
> In order to export data you must first be using the table from which the data will be exported.  As before, you will be employing the USE command in the command window.

```
USE <tablename>
```

> For example:

```
USE Mytest.dbf
```

> Once the table is in use, all you need to do is type the following command in the command window:

```
COPY TO <filename> TYPE DELIMITED
```

> For example:

```
COPY TO Myexport.txt TYPE DELIMITED
```

> This would result in a file being created in the current directory called Myexport.txt which would be in the DELIMITED or *.CSV format.
>
> If we had wanted to export the data in the *.SDF format, we would have typed:

```
COPY TO Myexport.txt TYPE SDF
```

> This would result in a file being created in the current directory called Myexport.txt which would be in the System Delimted or *.SDF format.
>
> Those are the basics on how to import and export text data into a dBASE table. For further information consult the on-line help for the APPEND FROM and COPY TO commands.

Answer (score 0):

I converted old (circa 1997) DBF files to CSV using Python and the [dbfread](https://dbfread.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) module.

After installation of Python, from the Python interpreter (`<WIN> + 'Python'`) install the **dbfread** module:

```
>>> pip install dbfread
```

The module has many method to read DBF files and excellent documentation.

Then a Python script does the job, or typing directly into the interpreter:

```
# Read the DBF file
table = DBF('C:/my_dbf_file.dbf', encoding='1252')
outFileName = 'C:/my_export.csv'
    with open(outFileName, 'w', newline='', encoding='1252' ) as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow(table.field_names)
    
        for record in table:
            writer.writerow(list(record.values()))
```

Note that each record in the database is read and save one at a time and that the first line of the CSV file are the column's names.

Encoding could be problematic, a list of encoding to try is [here](http://dbf-software.com/dbf-file-encoding.html): The `dbread.DBF()` method tries to guess the encoding but is not perfect. This is why in the code I specify the parameters encoding in both `DBF()` and `csv.open()`.